# How To Include CSS and jQuery in my WordPress plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

How To Include CSS and jQuery in my WordPress plugin ?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

For styles `wp_register_style( 'namespace', 'http://locationofcss.com/mycss.css' );`

Then use: `wp_enqueue_style('namespace');` wherever you want the css to load.

Scripts are as above but the quicker way for loading jquery is just to use enqueue loaded in an init for the page you want it to load on: `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');`

Unless of course you want to use the google repository for jquery.

You can also conditionally load the jquery library that your script is dependent on:

`wp_enqueue_script('namespaceformyscript', 'http://locationofscript.com/myscript.js', array('jquery'));`

**Update Sept. 2017**

I wrote this answer a while ago.  I should clarify that the best place to enqueue your scripts and styles is within the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.  So for example:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'callback_for_setting_up_scripts');
function callback_for_setting_up_scripts() {
    wp_register_style( 'namespace', 'http://locationofcss.com/mycss.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'namespace' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'namespaceformyscript', 'http://locationofscript.com/myscript.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
```

The `wp_enqueue_scripts` action will set things up for the "frontend".  You can use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` action for the backend (anywhere within wp-admin) and the `login_enqueue_scripts` action for the login page.

Comment: For those of us new to plugin development, could you please clarify "where ever you want the css to load?" Do we have to create page templates for each page where we want this to be called and then manually call it in the header?

Comment: @user658182 use ```add_action('init', 'function_name');```, where function_name is a function that enqueues the resources.

Comment: How can you make the style sheet work only if is on particular plugin?

Comment: Please could you provide us any link to a good documentation related to the new manner to achieve it ;) !!! Thanks

Comment: do I have to reinitialize something after the enqueue command? or just reload the page?

Comment: this worked like a charm, although i had to use the function "plugins_url" , since global paths result in a 404 on a standart apache2 (and should always do so!) -> see the wordpress reference under wp_register_style() for a good example

Answer (score 65):

Put it in the `init()` function for your plugin.

```
function your_namespace() {
    wp_register_style('your_namespace', plugins_url('style.css',__FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_style('your_namespace');
    wp_register_script( 'your_namespace', plugins_url('your_script.js',__FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_script('your_namespace');
}

add_action( 'admin_init','your_namespace');
```

It took me also some time before I found the (for me) best solution which is foolproof imho.

Cheers

Comment: Where does this code go? functions.php? Plugin.php?

Comment: @user658182 your wordpress plugin should probably have its own .php file or folder in wp-content/plugins/

Answer (score 38):

To include CSS and jQuery in your plugin is easy, try this:

```
// register jquery and style on initialization
add_action('init', 'register_script');
function register_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'custom_jquery', plugins_url('/js/custom-jquery.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '2.5.1' );

    wp_register_style( 'new_style', plugins_url('/css/new-style.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all');
}

// use the registered jquery and style above
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_style');

function enqueue_style(){
   wp_enqueue_script('custom_jquery');

   wp_enqueue_style( 'new_style' );
}
```

I found this great snipped from this site [How to include jQuery and CSS in WordPress – The WordPress Way](http://www.ryansutana.name/wordpress/how-to-include-jquery-and-css-in-wordpress-the-wordpress-way/)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 11):

Accepted answer is incomplete. You should use the right hook: `wp_enqueue_scripts`

Example:

```
    function add_my_css_and_my_js_files(){
        wp_enqueue_script('your-script-name', $this->urlpath  . '/your-script-filename.js', array('jquery'), '1.2.3', true);
        wp_enqueue_style( 'your-stylesheet-name', plugins_url('/css/new-style.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', "add_my_css_and_my_js_files");
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been struggling with this.

Answer (score 10):

Just to append to @pixeline's answer (tried to add a simple comment but the site said I needed 50 reputation).

If you are writing your plugin for the admin section then you should use:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', "add_my_css_and_my_js_files");
```

The admin_enqueueu_scripts is the correct hook for the admin section, use wp_enqueue_scripts for the front end.

Answer (score 7):

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Example

```
<?php
function my_init_method() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js');
}    

add_action('init', 'my_init_method');
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

First you need to register the style and css using wp_register_script() and wp_register_style() functions

```
 //registering javascript and css
 wp_register_script ( 'mysample', plugins_url ( 'js/myjs.js', __FILE__ ) );
 wp_register_style ( 'mysample', plugins_url ( 'css/mystyle.css', __FILE__ ) );
```

After this you can call the wp_enqueue_script() and wp_enqueue_style() functions for loading the js and css in required page

```
wp_enqueue_script('mysample');
wp_enqueue_style('mysample');
```

I fount a nice example here http://wiki.workassis.com/wordpress-create-advanced-custom-plugin-using-oop/

Answer (score 4):

*Very Simple:*

Adding JS/CSS in the **Front End**:

```
function enqueue_related_pages_scripts_and_styles(){
        wp_enqueue_style('related-styles', plugins_url('/css/bootstrap.min.css', __FILE__));
        wp_enqueue_script('releated-script', plugins_url( '/js/custom.js' , __FILE__ ), array('jquery','jquery-ui-droppable','jquery-ui-draggable', 'jquery-ui-sortable'));
    }
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_related_pages_scripts_and_styles');
```

Adding JS/CSS in WP **Admin Area**:

```
function enqueue_related_pages_scripts_and_styles(){
        wp_enqueue_style('related-pages-admin-styles',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/admin-related-pages-styles.css');
        wp_enqueue_script('releated-pages-admin-script', plugins_url( '/js/custom.js' , __FILE__ ), array('jquery','jquery-ui-droppable','jquery-ui-draggable', 'jquery-ui-sortable'));
    }
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_related_pages_scripts_and_styles');
```

Answer (score 2):

For css

```
wp_register_style('style-css',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'css/style.css');
```

for js

```
 wp_register_script('script-js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'js/script.js',array(), '1.0.0', true);
```

you can use the css by enqueue them in any page like

```
wp_enqueue_style('style-css');
```

you can use the js by enqueue them in any page like

```
wp_enqueue_script('script-js');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function to enqueue script or style from plugin.

```
function my_enqueued_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_script('my-js-file', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/js/script.js', '', time());
    wp_enqueue_style('my-css-file', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/css/style.css', '', time());
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueued_assets');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add scripts and css in back end and front end with this following code:
This is simple class and the functions are called in object oriented way.

```
class AtiBlogTest {
function register(){
    //for backend
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'backendEnqueue'));
    //for frontend
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'frontendEnqueue'));
}
function backendEnqueue(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'AtiBlogTestStyle', plugins_url( '/assets/css/admin_mystyle.css', __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'AtiBlogTestScript', plugins_url( '/assets/js/admin_myscript.js', __FILE__ ));
}
function frontendEnqueue(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'AtiBlogTestStyle', plugins_url( '/assets/css/front_mystyle.css', __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'AtiBlogTestScript', plugins_url( '/assets/js/front_myscript.js', __FILE__ ));
}
}

if(class_exists('AtiBlogTest')){
$atiblogtest=new AtiBlogTest();
$atiblogtest->register();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean the js and css files or code? If you have very little scripts or styling used, you can simply use them inline. But it's recommended to use following [wordpress  plugin](https://www.iworksolo.com/um-block-user/) functions if you want to include files.

wp_register_script()
wp_enqueue_style()

Hope it helps.