# Add CSS to Php Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins

I wrote a simple plugin which sets some css code using wp_options. It all looks similar like this:

```
add_action('init','easy_style');

function easy_style()
{
    ?>
    <style>
    #header a {
        color: <?php echo get_option('topcolor'); ?>;
        font-size: <?php echo get_option('topsize'); ?>px;
        <?php
            if (get_option('topstyle') == "bold")
            { echo "font-weight: bold;"; echo "font-style: normal;"; }
            elseif (get_option('topstyle') == "italic")
            { echo "font-style: italic;"; echo "font-weight: normal;"; }
            elseif (get_option('topstyle') == "bolditalic")
            { echo "font-weight: bold;"; echo "font-style: italic;"; }
            else { echo "font-weight: normal;"; echo "font-style: normal;"; }
        ?>;
    }

    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Now this works, but if I activate my "Contact Form 7" plugin, the contact form 7 doesn't work anymore. It can't send any mails. So I think what I do is wrong. If I remove this piece of code, the contact form works again...

I think I do it wrong because the css needs to be loaded in the header, no?
So what I thought I would do as a test is put the same code in the header. However then some other css (i don't know where) overwrites these, so this also doesn't work.

I think there are some wp functions to add css code to the header but I don't know how exacly.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38050537/1153703

Answer (score -14, accepted):

I solved my problem by loading in the styles.css file, edit it and save again

Comment: You really do want to switch to using enqueu style. That's going to leave your plugin stronger and less likely to break when new versions of WP come out.

Answer (score 30):

A safe way to add CSS to your plugin is to use `wp_enqueue_style`.

```
/**
 * Register with hook 'wp_enqueue_scripts', which can be used for front end CSS and JavaScript
 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_add_my_stylesheet' );

/**
 * Enqueue plugin style-file
 */
function prefix_add_my_stylesheet() {
    // Respects SSL, Style.css is relative to the current file
    wp_register_style( 'prefix-style', plugins_url('style.css', __FILE__) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'prefix-style' );
}
```

[Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style).

Comment: I tried writing to a css file and then registering it using your code. It loads the CSS file, however I seem to be having the same problems as before. It's the same as when I put it in the header file.

Comment: I noticed that some of the css code works, but some isn't. For example font-size & font-weight on menu links work, but color doesn't seem to change. Any ideas?

Comment: That will be because your template CSS is overriding your plugin CSS. Take a look at the order of inclusion and CSS specificity: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the plugin you are using wants to send some http headers.

Since you are using the **init** hook (detailed here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) you are running some actions when the plugin developers consider that the headers are not already sent.

But since you send some output (echo some styles) you are forcing the headers to be sent sooner. I suggest you to use another hook that occurs after the output is already started.

**Update:** you could use the wp_enqueue_style function (reference here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) as it is the recommended way to display styles. You only need to save those rules in a css file and en-queue it to be loaded before the wp_head function is called

Comment: This helped me solve the problem! You're right, the "init" is the problem. I changed it to "wp_loaded" and now the contact form works again. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Seems i was wrong, it worked locally, but on my host i get:

Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/gnc0081000/domains/claeysparts.be/public_html/wp-content/plugins/easy-styler.php:18) in /home/gnc0081000/domains/claeysparts.be/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 866

Comment: @WtFudgE that's the exact same thing, just read the error message. you are printing something before using the header function. It's the same thing I said above but in a part of the script that I don't have access to, but the error message tells you where the error is: in /home/gnc0081000/domains/claeysparts.be/public_html/wp-content/plugins/easy-styl‌​er.php at line 18

Answer (score -1):

In a plugin **dev**, do not forget to send the reference of the `class ($this)`

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'prefix_add_my_stylesheet' ));
```