# adding js files and css files to wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress.. I have installed my theme named 'hare'. Now I want to add some javascripts files as well as css files into the index.php page. But I am not finding the desired output.

following is the code i have written..

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    // Some content
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
<!-- JQuery libs
================================================== -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- js jQuery wait for images Plugin ====================== -->
<script src="<?php bloginfo(template_directory ); ?>/javascripts/jquery.waitforimages.js"></script>
<!-- js jQuery flexslider Plugin ====================== -->
<script src="<?php bloginfo(template_url); ?>/javascripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Cycle Plugin ====================================== -->
<script src="<?php bloginfo(template_url); ?>/javascripts/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Cycle Plugin ====================================== -->
<script src="<?php bloginfo(template_url); ?>/javascripts/jquery.fullscreen-min.js"></script>
<!-- js jQuery jcarousellite Plugin ====================== -->
<script src="<?php bloginfo(template_url); ?>/javascripts/jcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- js Fancybox Plugin ================================= -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo(template_directory); ?>/javascripts/fancyBox-2/jquery.fancybox.css">
<script src="<?php bloginfo(template_url); ?>/javascripts/fancyBox-2/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<!--fancybox helpers-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo(template_directory); ?>/javascripts/fancyBox-2/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css"/>
<script src="<?php bloginfo(template_url); ?>/javascripts/fancyBox-2/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<!-- js jQuery qtip plugin ====================== -->
<script src="<?php bloginfo(template_url); ?>/javascripts/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js"></script>
<!-- toTop ====================== -->
<script src="<?php bloginfo(template_url); ?>/javascripts/goToTop.js"></script>
<!-- js jQuery my own functions ====================== -->
<script src="<?php bloginfo(template_url); ?>/javascripts/functions.js"></script>


<!-- <script src="javascripts/jquery.tweet.js"></script> -->

<!-- JS twitter scripts ================================== -->
<script src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/EnvatoWebDesign.json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=5"></script>

    <!-- End Document
    ================================================== -->
    </body>

    </html>
```

Is my this way is correct??
If not then please correct me..

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why is this tagged as CakePHP?

Comment: Can you show one line and how it is not working as you want it to? Is it pointing to the wrong path, or is something else going wrong?

Comment: @RichardAtHome  : sorry I wanedt to tag php but instead i tagged Cakephp

Comment: @Pekka웃: I am not finding effect of any css or js files..

Comment: What does that mean - are the paths in the page? What exactly are you getting in the HTML source code, do you see any mention of your files? Can you show which files were already included, and which ones you added?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I am not able to add my output window here..But in output I am getting only texts and mentioned all files are included by me

Comment: What exactly are you getting in the HTML source code?

Comment: Your question is linked as an example on a bad question! Gratz! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163404/does-a-how-to-debug-css-reference-question-exist

Comment: @Oscar well that's not *exactly* what I'm saying. I'm saying this type of situation needs a step-by-step guide that we can give users to work with - instead of repeating the same advice over and over.

Comment: @Pekka웃 lol ya whatever :p make a wiki post about it then

Comment: for exapmple I am finding html code for 
   <script src="<?php bloginfo(template_url); ?>/javascripts/fancyBox-2/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script> 
As 
   <script src="javascripts/fancyBox-2/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

Comment: thnq all for help but I found that this method is right, problem was on another point..

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38050537/1153703

Answer (score 1):

In your comments you may be referring to [these guidelines from yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/high-performance-sites-rule-6-move-scripts-bottom-7200.html). There are, however a few caveats to this rule. Most importantly, Google Analytics prefers it's snippet be placed within the `<head>` section and won't allow you to use Analytics for Webmaster Tools authentication unless the snippet is in head.

More importantly, you don't want to include your JS and CSS files directly in your theme templates like this. It works, but it is very un-WordPress-y.

The "correct" way to include additional scripts and styles in a WordPress theme is to use the `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` [functions](http://wordpress.org/search/wp_enqueue_style) within a hook in functions.php, like so:

```
function my_custom_styles_function() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_stylesheet_directory() . DS . 'javascript' . DS . 'my-plugin' . DS . 'my-plugin-style.css', array(), '1.0' );
    ...
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_styles_function');
```

WordPress actually has jQuery included by default, although without the `$` shortcut established. You can use WordPress's jQuery and start all of your custom scripts with `jQuery(...);` instead of `$(...);` but this can cause problems for some plugins. If you want to include your own version of jquery, you should first use `wp_dequeue_style()` to [dequeue](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style) the "built-in" jQuery.

Finally, if you *do* want to include you scripts in the footer, the `wp_enqueue_script()` function has a flag, `$in_footer` to defer particular scripts to the footer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provide by  @qccreative is the right one. You should include all the js/css files you need to your page using the functions.php file that you must have within your theme. if you dont have it just create one and make a function for import your files just like the answer above.

you can even manage in what page you want to load your scripts.

also this is the safest way WP provide for including scripts in an organized way.

this hook that wordpress provide WP_ENQUEQUE_SCRIPTS its a function that will add the scripts within your action to the site.

heres another example:

```
function load_javascript_files(){

      wp_register_script( 'jquery-accordion', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.accordion.js', array('jquery'),true );
      wp_enqueue_script('jquery-accordion'); 
  }

 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_javascript_files');
```

Good luck buddy

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have put you would create a **header.php** file in your themes folder and include the JS in there. An example would be like follows:

```
    `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <script src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/jQuery-validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/style.css" type="text/css" />            
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: thnq for help but I have read somewhere that including js and css files will increase the speed of loading any page so I have included those files at the bottom..Is this true?? and yes my problem is solved which I have asked here..

Comment: So I have read yes, as all the other page content is loaded before the qujery if you load them in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles.
 */

    function custom_links() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_links' );
```

If you need to linked your CSS file than you can use **wp_enqueue_style** and if you need to linked JavaScript than you can use **wp_enqueue_script**.

**wp_enqueue_scripts** this is work on frontend side of wordpress.

**admin_enqueue_scripts** this is works on backend side of wordpress.

I hope it's help to all people.