# How to integrate a javascript to website's header cover in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a problem with using particle.js as my website's header cover in wordpress.

Actually where should the script be placed and the particle.js file is to be uploaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding js files and css files to wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279709/adding-js-files-and-css-files-to-wordpress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );

function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
```