# how can i can call css on a php file in Wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Include CSS and jQuery in my wordpress plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760222/how-to-include-css-and-jquery-in-my-wordpress-plugin)

I was going to add a button on a wordpress plugin

I want to add a style on button I know the basic way to call a css into a html file like.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="buttonPro.css">
```

but its not working on a php file

Comment: Show your code. Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760222/how-to-include-css-and-jquery-in-my-wordpress-plugin

Comment: The typically PHP file just outputs HTML, so that will work. (All else being equal, the usually rules of the cascade and having to have the right URL apply)

Answer (score 0):

You can call it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>
/css/style.css" media="screen" />
```

When your style sheet is living in a subdirectory called 'css' and the actual file is called 'style.css'. Don't forget to escape the HTML code in php:

```
<?php 
   put some php code here
?>

   **put some HTML code here**

<?php
   now you can continue with php
?>
```