# Load js and css files for custom wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

In my `wp-contents/pugins` folder, I have `program-registration`. Inside this plugin I have `js/registration.js` and `css/registration.css`.

Why the function defined in this js file is not accessible?

```
<?php

/*
*   Plugin Name: Program Registration
*   Plugin URI: http://www.test.com/
*   Description: Program Registration plugin for wordpress.
*   Version: 1.0.0
*   Author: Admin
*   Author URI: http://test.com/
*/

global $wpdb;
global $success;
global $error;

define('PROGRAM_REGISTRATION_TABLE', $wpdb->prefix . "program_registration");

/*
|--------------------------------
| Process Registration Form
|--------------------------------
*/

if( isset($_POST['program_register']) ) { 

    try {

        if ( !empty($_POST['candidate_name']) && !empty($_POST['candidate_address']) && !empty($_POST['candidate_phone']) && !empty($_POST['program']) ) {

            $rows_affected = $wpdb->insert(PROGRAM_REGISTRATION_TABLE, array('candidate_name' => $_POST['candidate_name'],'address' => $_POST['candidate_address'], 'email' => $_POST['candidate_email'], 'phone' => $_POST['candidate_phone'], 'program' => $_POST['program'], 'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) );

            if($rows_affected == 1) {
                $success = "You are successfully registered, you will get informed!";
            } else {
                $error   = "Something went wrong!";
            }
//echo $wpdb->last_query;

        } else {

            if( empty($_POST['candidate_name']) ) {
                throw new Exception("Candidate Name cannot be empty!");
            } elseif ( empty($_POST['candidate_address']) ) {
                throw new Exception("Address cannot be empty!");
            } elseif( empty($_POST['candidate_phone']) ) {
                throw new Exception("Phone cannot be empty!");
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Program cannot be empty!");
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
    }

}

/*
|--------------------------------
| Activate Plugin
|--------------------------------
*/

function program_registration_activation() {

    $registration_table = "CREATE TABLE ".PROGRAM_REGISTRATION_TABLE."(
        id int not null auto_increment,
        candidate_name varchar(100),
        address varchar(250),
        email varchar(50),
        phone varchar(20),
        program varchar(250),
        ip varchar(100),
        request_time timestamp,
        primary key(id)
    );";

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($registration_table);
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'program_registration_activation');

/*
|--------------------------------
| Deactivate Plugin
|--------------------------------
*/

function program_registration_deactivation() {

}

register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'program_registration_deactivation');

/*
|--------------------------------
| Stylesheets
|--------------------------------
*/

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'registration_styles');

function registration_styles() {  
    wp_register_style('program_style', plugins_url('css/registration.css', __FILE__));  
    wp_enqueue_style('program_style');  
}

/*
|--------------------------------
| Scripts
|--------------------------------
*/

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'registration_scripts');

function registration_scripts() {  

    wp_register_script('registrationjs_init', plugins_url('js/registration.js', __FILE__));  
    wp_enqueue_script('registrationjs_init');

}

/*
|--------------------------------
| Shortcode
|--------------------------------
*/

add_shortcode('registration_form', 'registration_form_function');

function registration_form_function() {

    global $success;
    global $error;

    $form  = "";
    if(isset($success) && $success != '') {
        $form .= "<div class='alert alert-success'>
                    <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert' type='button'>×</button>
                    <strong>Well done! </strong>";
        $form .= $success."</div>";
    } elseif(isset($error) && $error != '') {
        $form .= "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                    <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert' type='button'>×</button>
                    <strong>Error! </strong>";
        $form .= $error."</div>";
    }

    $form .= "<form method='POST' name='program_registration_form' action=''>
                <label for='candidate_name' class='registration_label'>Candidate Name:</label>
                <input type='text' name='candidate_name' class='txbx' required/> 
                <label for='candidate_address' class='registration_label'>Address:</label>
                <textarea name='candidate_address' class='txbx' required></textarea>
                <label for='candidate_email' class='registration_label'>E-mail:</label>
                <input type='email' name='candidate_email' class='txbx'/> 
                <label for='candidate_phone' class='registration_label'>Phone:</label>
                <input type='text' name='candidate_phone' class='txbx' required/> 
                <label for='program' class='registration_label'>Interested Program:</label>
                <input type='text' name='program' class='txbx' required/> 
                <input type='submit' name='program_register' value='Register' class='button blue small'/> 
            </form>";
    return $form;
}

/*
|--------------------------------
| Admin Settings Menu
|--------------------------------
*/

function program_plugin_settings() {
    // add_management_page
    add_menu_page( 'Program Registration', 'Program Registration', 'administrator', 'program_settings', 'program_settings_display');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'program_plugin_settings');


/*
|--------------------------------
| Admin Settings Page
|--------------------------------
*/

function program_settings_display() {

    $html = '<h2>Program Registration Panel</h2>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>S.No.</th>
                    <th >Candidate Name</th>
                    <th >Address</th>
                    <th >E-mail</th>
                    <th >Phone</th>
                    <th >Requested Program</th>
                    <th >Action</th>
                </tr>';
    $sql  = "SELECT * FROM ".PROGRAM_REGISTRATION_TABLE.""; 

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $i = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $html .= '<tr>
                    <td>'.$i.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row->candidate_name.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row->address.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row->email.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row->phone.'</td>
                    <td>'.$row->program.'</td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:void(null);" onclick="delete_registration('.$row->id.');">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>';
                $i++;
    }       

    $html .= '</table>';
    echo $html;
}
```

Comment: If you view the source of a generated page, does your registration.js appear in a <script> tag?  It may be failing to get enqueued, or there might be some other problem (like an error in another js file, or a dependency (like jQuery) that you're not explicitly defining).  If it is in the source, are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @Hobo My js or css file does not appear in generated source, there is no errors in firebug console.

Comment: Ok, that helps.  I assume you've activated the plugin in the admin console?  Any errors in your PHP logs?  One thing that could cause problems is a function name clash - see http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Avoiding_Function_Name_Collisions

Comment: @Hobo There is no errors, I can access the plugin in admin panel and I can see the delete function link here (``program_settings_display()``).

Comment: Now I'm confused.  I copied your plugin, created a `js` subdirectory containing a file called `registration.js` and the equivalent `css/registration.css`.  Activated your plugin and both the script and stylesheet are appearing in my page source.  Have you checked the spelling of your filenames?  Does it work if you deactivate all other plugins?  What if you use one of the default themes?  I'm running WordPress 3.8.1,  Twenty Fourteen theme, with only your plugin active, and it works.

Comment: @Hobo Everything looks correct but it does not appear, am also using same version.

Comment: Even if you disable all other plugins and switch to a default theme?  Just wondering if there's a clash.  Any of the suggestions on https://codex.wordpress.org/Managing_Plugins#Troubleshooting help?

Comment: @Hobo No luck, tested in local fresh installation with only this plugin.

Comment: Bizarre.  Any chance there are typos in the file names (mismatches between the names in the code and the directory names and/or file names)?  Really can't think of anything else.

Comment: Nope, I can't any typos.

Comment: Can you zip the plugin's directory and share it somewhere so I can take a look?

Comment: See here https://github.com/anshad/wp-program-registration

Comment: Sorry, no idea.  I downloaded the zip of your code, extracted it into the same setup I mentioned yesterday, activated it, and I can see both the css and js files in the generated page source.  If I change the js file to just contain `alert("Test");` I get the alert on page load.  As far as I can see, the plugin's fine.  And you can't see them in a fresh installation with no plugins and a standard theme?

Comment: Eh...thanks for helping, anyway give me some more time to check it.

Comment: We don't need to see the whole plugin. If you reduce this to `wp_enqueue_*` and very simple CSS + JS files, does it bug?

Comment: @brasofilo I am not clear.

Comment: @Hobo Thanks for your help, solved the problem using ``admin_enqueue_scripts``

Comment: Aaargh!  You never said they weren't showing up in the _admin_ screen - I only checked the scripts were available in the front end.  D'oh.  Glad you've solved the mystery at least.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38050537/1153703

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load js and css files in wordpress admin panel plugin settings, we need to call `admin_enqueue_scripts` like this,

So here it will be,

```
function registration_scripts() {  

    wp_register_script('registrationjs_init', plugins_url('js/registration.js', __FILE__));  
    wp_enqueue_script('registrationjs_init');

}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'registration_scripts' );
```