# Load Css, JS plugin and Custom Script file into wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, parent-child

Been having a hard time getting this to work... I'm trying to use animation for some transitions on a website I'm working on but when I include the files the average way it breaks the theme... A lot of reading has brought me knowing I need to use functions.php to enqueue the scripts and CSS but I tried and no dice.

***I am using a child theme***

The CSS I need to load is located in a folder my child-theme's directory called "css", the custom js and plugin js I need to load is located in a folder in my child-themes directory called "js".

1-The CSS needs to be in the header

2-jQuery needs to load

3-The plugin then needs to load

4-My scripts.js file needs to load, it manipulates the plugin's settings.

If you still don't understand this then basically I want to use http://git.blivesta.com/animsition/ within a wordpress child-theme. Thanks.

Comment: What do you expect as an answer? Please try to focus and be more accurate, it would help you and others.

Comment: I have explained what answer i want, i want to know how to properly make wordpress render my scripts without me breaking my theme which is what is currently happening. Iv been reading on how to wpenqueue and wpregister etc but still i cant get this to work on wordpress like i have it working offline.

please assist if you could. Basically i cannot go about making this work the same way i have it offline because there is already a jquery in wp and i dont know how to reference it or my scripts from functions.php in my childtheme...still dont understand?

Comment: I understand and I am trying to help. Your question is too broad and actually you asked 4 questions in one. You could maybe divide your question and you should post some code (what you tried so far). Btw, you can add styles to child theme stylesheet, you do not need to load another jQuery because you already have it and the plugin script can go together with some other script. After that you need to debug and check what breaks your theme, styles or scripts.

Comment: question put simple: i do not know how...to...properly...enqueue...custom...js...scripts and css...into WordPress...using functions.php file and add action. If you still don't understand this then you can't answer my question, thanks for trying.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38050537/1153703

Answer (score 0):

Try reading https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes , it will help you a lot.

Regarding your question, you have to place the following code in your child's theme functions.php file:

```
function animsition_enqueue_styles_and_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style )
    );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'animsition-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/animsition.min.css' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'animsition-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.animsition.min.js',  array('jquery'), '20150628', false );     

    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-animsition-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js',  array('animsition-js','jquery'), '20150628', false ); 

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'animsition_enqueue_styles_and_styles' );
```

Comment: People are downvoting my question :( thanks for answering, i already have the child theme setup but i will still read into it. I really hope your answer works ill try it soon and let you know! thanks for replying