# localhost for wordpress: correct way to link reference css/js files?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to convert a Bootstrap layout to Wordpress, however I am facing some difficulties in linking js/css resources.

What worked for index.html ie.

```
<link href="./vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="./css/business-frontpage.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Doesn't seem to work in a header.php file even with the same file structure.

Previously I have tried to modify a Wordpress layout but I did it on a live site, have not tried doing so via localhost first, and I did not encounter this issue. Can anyone let me know the right way to do this?

Comment: get rid of the dot

Comment: You should put the js and css in the theme folder and use something like [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) to get the path to those files. Example: `<link href="<?= get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/css/business-frontpage.css" ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Include CSS and jQuery in my wordpress plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760222/how-to-include-css-and-jquery-in-my-wordpress-plugin)

Comment: Getting rid of the dot doesn’t work @delbot1978uk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move all static assets to your template directory and use `get_template_directory_url` function:

```
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/business-frontpage.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

More details here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/

Comment: There's an issue with `get_template_directory_uri()`. If the theme is a child theme, it will return the url to the master theme instead.

Comment: I didn't know. Do you have any solution for this issue?

Comment: Yepp, use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/

Answer (score 2):

**Enqueuing Scripts and Styles**

The proper way to add scripts and styles to your theme is to enqueue them in the `functions.php` files. The `style.css` file is required in all themes, but it may be necessary to add other files to extend the functionality of your theme.

**Stylesheets**

Your CSS stylesheets are used to customize the presentation of your theme. A stylesheet is also the file where information about your theme is stored.

Rather then loading the stylesheet in your `header.php` file, you should load it in using `wp_enqueue_style`. In order to load your main stylesheet, you can enqueue it in `functions.php`.

To enqueue `style.css`

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```

This will look for a stylesheet named *style* and load it.

The basic function for enqueuing a style is:

```
wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
```

- `$handle` is simply the name of the stylesheet.
- `$src` is where it is located. The rest of the parameters are optional.
- `$deps` refers to whether or not this stylesheet is dependent on another stylesheet. If this is set, this stylesheet will not be loaded unless its dependent stylesheet is loaded first.
- `$ver` sets the version number.
- `$media` can specify which type of media to load this stylesheet in, such as *all*, *screen*, *print* or *handheld*.

So if you wanted to load a stylesheet named `slider.css` in a folder named `CSS` in you theme’s root directory, you would use:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/slider.css',false,'1.1','all');
```

**Scripts**

Any additional JavaScript files required by a theme should be loaded using wp_enqueue_script. This ensures proper loading and caching, and allows the use conditional tags to target specific pages. These are optional.

**wp_enqueue_script** uses a similar syntax to **wp_enqueue_style**.

Enqueue your script:

```
wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer);
```

- `$handle` is the name for the script.
- `$src` defines where the script is located.
- `$deps` is an array that can handle any script that your new script depends on, such as jQuery.
- `$ver` lets you list a version number.
- `$in_footer` is a *boolean* (true/false) parameter that allows you to place your scripts in the footer of your HTML document rather then in the header, so that it does not delay the loading of the DOM tree.

Your enqueue function may look like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);
```

**Combining Enqueue Functions**

It is best to combine all enqueued scripts and styles into a single function, and then call them using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action. This function and action should be located somewhere below the initial setup (performed above).

```
function add_theme_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

   wp_enqueue_style( 'slider', get_template_directory_uri() . 
   '/css/slider.css', array(), '1.1', 'all');

    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . 
     '/js/script.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 1.1, true);

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) 
    ) {
     wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
  }
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_theme_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends where your working files are being stored. If they are within the root, you can simply remove the dot in your code and the files will be accessed from the root. For example, your bootstrap CSS file would be access by **www.mydomain.com**/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css.

If however you are putting these files within your theme, you would have to add `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>` where your dot is in order to link to your theme folder.

Comment: There's an issue with `get_template_directory_uri()`. If the theme is a child theme, it will return the url to the master theme instead.