# How to add animate css to my wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have started making wordpress theme , and want to use some animation for my blocks , "Animate css library" I have tried to add cdn link into header php , but it doesn't work , can you advice me something for ex. some installation guide ? I have also tried to import library from folder not cdn link , but i have the same result.Also i have read about another way - wp_register_style or enque script , but i don't know how it works?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered here: [How To Include CSS and jQuery in my WordPress plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760222/how-to-include-css-and-jquery-in-my-wordpress-plugin).

Include [this](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/master/animate.css) file in your theme directory and follow the link above on how to reference a .css file in your theme header. Hope this helps. Please include code examples of your issue in the future.