# Include css in wordpress plugin

Tags: php, css, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to include a css in my plugin, I found something related on stackoverflow, but it doesn't work out ! It is event not showing in console if the css file exists or not !

```
        if ($session_data['login_cashdrawer_mode'] == 'waiter') {
            
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'callback_for_setting_up_scripts');
            
        function callback_for_setting_up_scripts() {
         wp_register_style( 'namespace', 'http://locationofcss.com/mycss.css' );
         wp_enqueue_style( 'namespace' );
            }       

        }
```

Comment: [Might be helpful](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173106/wp-enqueue-script-not-working-at-all/325024)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Include CSS and jQuery in my WordPress plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760222/how-to-include-css-and-jquery-in-my-wordpress-plugin)